# Lambda triggers high s3 costs

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I created a new Lambda based on a 2MB zip file (it has a heavy dependency). After that, my S3 costs really increased (from $12.27 to $31).

**Question 1:** As this is uploaded from a CI/CD pipeline, could it be that it's storing every version and then increasing costs?

**Question 2:** Is this storage alternative more expensive than choosing directly an owned s3 bucket instead of the private one owned by Amazon where this zip goes? Looking at the S3 prices list, only 2MB can't result in 19 Dollars.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that Object versioning was enabled, and after some stress tests those versions were accumulated and stored. Costs went back to $12 after they were removed.

It's key to keep the "Show" enabled (see image) to keep track of those files. [image]

Answer (score 1):

few things you can do to mitigate cost:

1. Use Lambda Layers for dependencies
2. Use S3 Infrequent access for your lambda archive

Being that I don't have your full configuration of S3, its hard to tell what can be causing cost...things like S3 versioning would do it.

Comment: Thanks @LostJon. Could you add some information on point 2? Regarding point 1, I think it would only have impact in case of execution, but this lambda was not executed every day and still has the same S3 cost.

Comment: So, point #2, Infrequent Access means you are charged for less for storage, and more for IO. As for #1, lambda-layers means you wont be uploading your dependency code EVERY time you upload your lambda code. so you will feel the benefits down the road in terms of $$